# Laplace equation on a sphere, Legendre polynomials.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Solve the following dirichlet problem: $$\Delta u(r,\theta,\phi) = 0 $$ $$r < 1$$
$$u(1,\theta,\phi) = cos^2(\theta)sin^2(\phi)$$

After a lengthy calculation using seperation of variables we get the solution form: 
$$u(r,\theta,\phi) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-n}^{n} (Cmn)r^ne^{im\theta}P_n ^{|m|}(cos(\phi))$$

where $P_n ^{|m|}(\phi)$ is the associated Legendre function, and for

$$u(1,\theta,\phi) = cos^2(\theta)sin^2(\phi) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-n}^{n} (Cmn)e^{im\theta}P_n ^{|m|}(cos(\phi))$$

we can derive the integral solution for $Cnm$

$$Cnm = \frac{(2n-1)(n-|m|)!}{4\pi(n+|m|)!}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos^2(\theta)sin^2(\phi)e^{-im\theta}P_n ^{|m|}(cos(\phi))sin(\phi)d\theta d\phi$$

But at this point I am kinda lost. I have no idea where to begin computing this integral, or what to do with m & n. The main problem is of course the legendre functions, everything else is straight forward. Do we compute a general formula for the associated legendre function, and plug that in? Am I misintepreting the solution forms? I have worked a lot with basic orthogonal bases and a bit with regular legendre polynomials but at this point I am stumped. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hang on, is your convention that the angle from the $z$-axis is $\phi$? That's the opposite of the usual one.

Comment: Yeah, in mathematics it's usually done like that. I hear that in physics they do it the other way.

Comment: Not in my department, at least. We're all one happy $(\cos{\phi}\sin{\theta},\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta},\cos{\theta})$ family. :) Just don't ask about what happens in more than 3D...

Comment: @chappers  Huh! Well, the question and notation is from an american book (Fourier Analysis and It's applications, Folland) and in class they just mention that "if you are doing physics, you will most likely see this the other way around". Live and learn I guess!

Comment: Ah, then we get to play the American/European mutual unintelligibility game, rather than the Pure/Applied mutual unintelligibility game ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $\cos^2 \theta=\frac12(1+\cos 2\theta)$, we have

$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-im\theta}\cos^2 \theta \,d\theta=\frac12 \int_0^{2\pi}e^{-im\theta}(1+\cos 2\theta) \,d\theta=\pi\delta_{m,0}+\frac12\pi\delta_{m,2}+\frac12\pi\delta_{m,-2}$$

So, now the only terms that are non-zero are $C_{n,0}$, $C_{n,2}$, and $C_{n,-2}$.  The requisite integrals are

$$\int_0^\pi P_n^0(\cos \phi)\,\sin^3 \phi\,d\phi=\int_0^\pi P_n^0(\cos \phi)\,(1-\cos^2\phi)\,\sin \phi\,d\phi \tag 1$$

$$\int_0^\pi P_n^2(\cos \phi)\,\sin^3 \phi\,d\phi=\int_0^\pi P_n^2(\cos \phi)\,(1-\cos^2\phi)\,\sin \phi\,d\phi \tag 2$$

Now, note that $P_0^0=1$, $P_2^0=\frac12(3\cos^2\phi -1)$, and $P_2^2=3(1-\cos^2 \phi)$.  Then in $(1)$, we have

$$1-\cos^2 \phi=\frac23(P_0^0-P_2^0)$$

while in $(2)$, we have

$$1-\cos^2 \phi=\frac13 P_2^2$$

Now, simply exploit the orthogonal property of the Associated Legendre Functions

$$\int_0^\pi P_n^m(\cos \phi)P_{n'}^m(\cos \phi)\,\sin \phi\,d\phi=\frac{2(n+m)!}{(2n+1)(n-m)!}\delta_{n,n'}$$

and you will have it!

Comment: Chris, are you familiar with the orthogonal relationships among the Associated Legendre Functions?

Comment: The answer I would have written had my officemate not just arrived and felt it necessary to have an explosion at the indignities of the world. (+1)

Comment: @Chappers Now that was funny!  Remember to thank your officemate for his explosiveness.  And thank you for the +1.  - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, I am! That each $P_{n}^{m} and P_{n'}^{m} $ are mutually orthogonal with in $L^2(-1,1)$  ?

Comment: @Chris Yes.  In fact, I added the orthogonality relationship in the answer.  It should be fairly straightforward now to apply.

Comment: And thank you for the best vote!  Much appreciative!!  ;-))

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Assuming that all your development is correct.

For $m>0$
$$C_{nm} = \frac{(2n-1)(n-m)!}{4\pi(n+m)!}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos^2(\theta)sin^2(\phi)e^{-im\theta}P_n ^{m}(cos(\phi))sin(\phi)d\theta d\phi$$
For $m<0$
$$C_{nm} = \frac{(2n-1)(n+m)!}{4\pi(n-m)!}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos^2(\theta)sin^2(\phi)e^{im\theta}P_n ^{-m}(cos(\phi))sin(\phi)d\theta d\phi$$

Finaly, for $m=0$ 
$$C_{n0} = \frac{(2n-1)}{4\pi }\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos^2(\theta)sin^2(\phi) sin(\phi)d\theta d\phi$$

The last one I'm pretty sure you know to solve.
In the first two, first change the variables from $\phi$ to $t=\cos\phi$ (I guess I don't need to say it, but don't forget the differentials and the limits). Next, change the Legender polynomial to its differential definition
$$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n n!}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left[
(x^2-1)^n\right]
$$

another thing you could try is 
\begin{align}P_n(x)= 2^n\cdot \sum_{k=0}^n x^k {n \choose k}{\frac{n+k-1}2\choose n}\end{align}

One of them should be solvable. Also, I like the answer by Dr. MV

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out!

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: @Dr. MV The main question was about what to do with m,n and the Legender polynomials. Since this answer the question - it is supposed to help.

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky Well, I know that you're trying to help.   I am struggling to see an easy way forward with presenting Rodrigues'  Formula for the Legendre Polynomials when we have Associated Legendre Functions $P_n^m$ with $m \ne 0$.

Comment: @Dr. MV An integration by parts was in my mind in general. Although, I've upvoted your answer since it is reduces the work.